# Swift 3 Do not Recognize headers Mobile Engagement

Tags: ios, azure, swift3, azure-mobile-services

I have followed this manual
https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/mobile-engagement/mobile-engagement-ios-swift-get-started.md
I have been doing step by step the indications.
But when I run my project, obtains
AEModule.h file not found, AEPushMessage.h file not found ...
Add screensshots
[image][image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a bridging header to use that library? If you already included it as a framework you should be able to import the header directly where you want to use it and treat it as if it was written in Swift. Bridging headers are used for when your OWN code has both objective-c and swift and you need to connect them somehow.

Comment: hi @Chiquis, because mobile azure was written in Objective C and my code is Swift 3.
Step 6. Edit the bridging header file to expose Mobile Engagement Objective-C Reach headers and add the following imports :

Comment: Try cleaning the project and delete derived data, then click the run button even if there are compile errors. Sometimes weird compiler errors disappear after clicking the run button.

Comment: Hi @DevB2F , I try your advice...but still..not working :(